# Translating js notifications to other languages

Tags: magento-2.1

There are some javascript messages in the file `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`.

Like the message `Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than 8 symbols.` when the customer sets password during registration.

I need to translate all such messages to Persian.

How can I do that?

**Edit 1**

**My csv file**

```
"Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols.","ﺡﺩﺎﻘﻟ ﻁﻮﻟ ﺮﻣﺯ ﻊﺑﻭﺭ %1 کﺍﺭﺍکﺕﺭ ﺎﻧگﻝیﺱی ﺏﺯﺭگ ﻭ کﻭچک ﻭ ﺱیﻢﺒﻟ ﻡی ﺏﺎﺷﺩ"
```

Comment: Have you create persion language csv file?

Comment: yes, it's in `app/i18n/mageplaza/fa_ir/fa_IR.csv` but it does not contain that javascript text.

Comment: where above message is coming from file?

Comment: `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`

Comment: have you created cusotm theme?

Comment: yes. Using a paid theme.

Comment: Is it that the csv file should be in `app/i18n/vendor_of_paid_theme/` ?

Comment: Just create fa_IR.csv file inside theme app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/i18n/fa_IR.csv and put content inside it. like, "Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than 8 symbols. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored","translated string" and run setup upgrade and deploy command

Comment: Thanks! Will I need just the fa_IR.csv file or also registration.php file?

Comment: YOu need to create new csv file and put inside theme i18n and run upgrade command

Comment: There's no `i18n` folder inside `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}`. Shall I create it manually?

Comment: You have to create manually

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Hye! I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: please show your csv file content in your question

Comment: Edited. Pls check!

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Is it ok. am I doing something Wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can put traslation string in first column and translated string another and module add "lib" in third column and path for this module add "lib/web/mage/validation.js" in 4th column in your "app/i18n/mageplaza/fa_ir/fa_IR.csv".
2. In terminal you can go to application path and fire below command

find . -name js-translation.json -exec rm -rf {} \;

it is remove js-translation.json in pub folder

3. Than deploy static content

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fa_IR

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not understandable. Can you make instructions more clear.

Comment: if yes than in that csv add js translation string that you want to translate as per magento 2 csv format first 2 column use for transltion string and transtlated string but 3 rd column use for module so in that column use "lib" for js translation and 4th column use "lib/web/mage/validation.js"

Comment: than you have to connect system from terminal and go to application path
like $>your_magento_path

Comment: than you can fire "find . -name js-translation.json -exec rm -rf {} \;" this command it will delete js teanslation file from pub folder

Comment: than deploy magento by "php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fa_IR